# What is the purpose of window.$ in the console?

Tags: javascript

Hopefully this isn't obvious, but I couldn't figure it out form reading the contents of the displayed function in the console nor could I find previous questions addressing it. What exactly is the purpose of `window.$` in the console and similar properties - e.g. `window.$w`?

What I saw:

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
    elements.push($(arguments[i]));
  return elements;
}
if (Object.isString(element))
    element = document.getElementById(element);
     return Element.extend(element);
}
```

Comment: `window` is the object to which "global" properties are attached. `$` is a variable.

Comment: I was viewing it in Chrome's developer tools. I also noticed the displayed function differed based on the page I was viewing. I apologize if this is very basic, I'm just starting to wrap my head around JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is widely dependent on the page you are viewing. Typically `$` is used to denote jQuery, but this is by no means a rule of thumb. Many libraries take advantage of the fact that `$` is a valid variable name in javascript to prefix objects.

You are best off looking through the code in the console to see what it means in the context in which you are referring to it.

If you see something that looks like the following, it is most likely jQuery.

```
>window.$
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variable which can be defined as any other variable.

```
var $ = "hello";
console.log(window.$); // will output "hello"
```

`window` means that the variable will be searched in the global scope

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared in the global scope is added to the `window` object. Explicitly mentioning the `window` allows you to fetch the global instance of that variable. You shouldn't really have multiple instances of the same variable name for legibility reasons - but it is possible:

```
var foo="bar";
function myfunc()
{
    var foo="foobar";
    return [foo,window.foo];
}
myfunc();//["foobar", "bar"]
```